# extract the text of a DOM element into a string var - why undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to JS development, and using jsonlib.fetch to get a JSON object and sidestep cross-domain issues in the browser. I wrote the response to a DOM element that i hide with CSS, and want to set a variable to the string I get back (JSON object) and convert it to an array for use later in the program.

```
jsonlib.fetch(apiurl, function(m) {

  $(".allQuestion").text(m.content);

 });

var allQuestions = $(".allQuestion").text();
```

However, I get undefined or a number of blank characters when I write allQuestions to the console. Why? Is there a better way to do this in general?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `fetch` method is an async method, so that method is still in progress when you try to grab the text. Do all your logic within the callback:

```
jsonlib.fetch(apiurl, function(m) {
    $(".allQuestion").text(m.content);
    var allQuestions = $(".allQuestion").text();
});
```